# Why is try-finally valid, but not try-else-finally?

Tags: python, syntax, exception

I found Python throwing a SyntaxError at me for trying `try` without `except`:

```
try:
    spam()
else:
    eggs()
finally:
    semprini()
```

Instead, I was forced to write:

```
try:
    spam()
except:
    raise
else:
    eggs()
finally:
    semprini()
```

which felt slightly silly, but I want `eggs()` to be executed *before* `semprini()` — if I put the contents of the `else:`-clause after the `finally:`-clause it will be executed *after* `semprini()`.  Although there has been a [`try` without `except` proposal](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2009-April/004298.html) in the past, the semantics were different as there the implication was `except: pass`, i.e. the polar opposite of what I'm after.  Interestingly, `try:` without either `except:` *or* `else:` [is valid](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement), but I can't have `else:` if I don't also have `except:`.  Although there may be a different way to formulate the same, the alternatives I've thought of (probably) have subtly different behaviour.

Why does the presence of `else:` require the presence of `except:`?

Comment: `try:` without `except:` *must* have a `finally:`

Comment: @TemporalWolf I can see that from the grammar, but I wonder why.

Comment: I assume because [explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): you must specify something (even if that something is nothing) if you tell python you think this may throw an exception.

Comment: @TemporalWolf and either way, the `SyntaxError` is not because `finally:` is missing, but because `except:` is missing.

Comment: `else` in this context means something like `if not except`, thus it makes no sense without any `except` clause

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have written

```
try:
    spam()
    eggs()
finally:
    semprini()
```

In the absence of any `except` clauses, `else` is useless.

Comment: Is that completely identical, though?

Comment: @gerrit: The only difference between the `try` and `else` clauses of a `try` statement is whether the `except` clauses apply to them. You don't *have* any `except` clauses.